# How do we find out who is using the router?

Tags: security, ip, home-networking

How do we see all the connections that a router currently has?

Is there a way to determine the IP addresses of the connected "users"?

Comment: I’m sorry, but this information is absolutely essential and hiding it behind a spoiler will solve nothing.

Comment: @DanielB, Np, the question is about getting a list of IP addresses of the users in the same network. My router may be Linksys, but this is not a Linksys question. It's a general networking question.

Comment: It's fine if you see it that way. The reality is, however, that every manufacturer has a different idea of how a router's web interface should look like. As such, there are only device-specific answers to this question. As it is now, the question simply cannot be answered.

Comment: @DanielB, It can be answered to a degree considered useful by people searching for the same question. Even an answer like *"No, it's not possible."* is fairly useful for someone with this question, assuming that *that* is the correct answer. And down the long road, [there may be](http://superuser.com/questions/303131/how-can-we-find-out-who-is-using-the-router?noredirect=1#comment-1135252) a standard.

Comment: From @xrobwx: Search Google for Nirsoft wireless network watcher. Works great and easy to use. or use this link. http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wnetwatcher_setup.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to your modem you can use the modem configuration interface by entering 192.168.1.1 in your browser and then use admin for both and if your router's firmware is same as me (I forgot the name, the stock firmware in most routers) you can see list of connected devices with their MAC address:
[image]

Also to check for their Ip address you can use [Advanced Port Scanner](http://www.radmin.com/download/previousversions/portscanner.php) which is a free tool out there. Also try [FING](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en) for android or ios which I think is better than Advanced Port Scanner.
Also you can use a port scanner like Angry IP Scaner and scan the range from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255
Also! [SoftPerfect Network Scanner](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/) could be another choice for windows

**Key features**

- Pings computers and displays those alive.
- Fully supports both IPv4 and IPv6 discovery.
- Detects hardware MAC-addresses, even across routers.
- Detects hidden shared folders and writable ones.
- Detects your internal and external IP addresses.
- Scans for listening TCP ports, some UDP and SNMP services.
- Retrieves currently logged-on users, configured user accounts, uptime, etc.
- Mounts and explores network resources.
- Launches external third party applications.
- Exports results to HTML, XML, CSV and TXT.
- Supports Wake-On-LAN, remote shutdown and sending network messages.
- Retrieves any system information via WMI, remote registry, file system and service manager.
- Absolutely free, requires no installation, and does not contain any adware, spyware or malware.

Comment: Really ? is it what you have wanted? Im glad! be happy!

Comment: :D *What* I wanted was actually an OS-independent command e.g. `get_ip_of_all_users` that works out-of-the-box on as many major platforms as possible (including the systems I'm currently using and will use in the future) without 3rd party installations. There might be such a thing in the future, but out of the 4 good answers so far, this is *currently* the best one.

Answer (score 2):

OK, Just got back to see your model was posted. I linked to the manual at the bottom.

Before you get started, if you don't know how to get into your router, you would open a command box and type in `ipconfig` and enter. Enter the gateway IP address into your web browser: The default username is blank with a password of admin. If it is the defaults, you should change this soon (see chapter 2 in your manual, which is only one page long).

A lot of these home routers do not let you see if someone is connected with a wire, but that is probably not of real concern, but rather, you want to see who is connected wirelessly.

The following info assumes that you have an idea what IP addresses you actually have on your network, and anything else could be an intruder.

First, one clue as to who is connected would be anyone with a DHCP address. You can see that on page 7 of your manual. If someone has set their IP address statically, it will not show in this list.

Second, the most important indicator that someone will be piggy-backing your wireless will be the "Wireless Client list". This is on page 15 of your manual.

Lastly, you can look at the logs. This is found on page 24 of your manual. You need to enable this feature, and how to do that is also on that page.

Here is your manual:

http://downloads.linksysbycisco.com/downloads/userguide/1224642949409/WRT120N_V10_UG_NC_EU.pdf

Comment: @Pacerier That was just how to find your router...Do you already know how to connect to it?

Comment: I saw your new question, so paragraph two is not releveant...you know how to at least connect to it, even if you don't know the password. That was just about finding the IP address to put in the web browser.

Answer (score 1):

First, input your default gateway IP into your browser. Then input your default username and password (or the default if you haven't changed it yet, which you should for security reasons.) Then you should get a log of all the devices on your network. If you see more devices than you know are using your network, someone is leeching. This way only gives you the MAC or physical address of the device, not the IP.

Comment: you can change the mac address on some devices. Its generally *not done* however.